# jQuery - variable in ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am very new to jQuery and would like to use variable `name` in the success function where it says `$(data.name)`. Is there anyway to do this? What I'm trying to do is, take the .html file name and then use that to retrieve data from a JSON file.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var name = filename.replace('.html','');

console.log(name);

$.ajax({
  url: '../content.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,

  success: function(data){
    $(data.name).each(function(index, value) {
      $("#title").text(value.title);
      $("#image").attr('src', value.image);
      $("#link").attr('href', value.link);
      $("#link").text(value.linktitle);
    });
  }
});
```

Here is content.json

```
{
  "getting_started_in_photography_for_beginners" : {
    "short_title" : "photography",
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "Getting started in Photography",
    "photo" : "asdfasdf",
    "link" : "fffsdfa"
  },
  "getting_started_in_filmmaking_for_beginners" : {
    "short_title" : "filmmaking",
    "id" : 2,
    "title" : "Getting started in Filmmaking",
    "photo" : "sgasdgw",
    "link" : "gssd"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give more details? it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Where it says `$(data.name)` I would like replace name with the variable `name`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please post your content.json file, or at least a small sample of it.  Trying to establish if your JSON contains members named after your file ... which is what you seem to be implying

Comment: it seems like data.name is a json with objects inside, so you can't replace that with the name variable that is a string. it seems like you want to add the name text in some part of the html, maybe the #title element? where do you want exactly to see the name value?

Comment: Frankly, this is a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Please update your question and explain the purpose of your script.

Comment: it seems your json response is like this? name:{ title:..., image:..., link:...., linktitle:.... }?

Comment: Just updated the question, hopefully this makes sense. I am 16 years old and don't know much about jQuery so I may be doing this backwards.

Comment: Andrew, you need to explain what you're trying to do.  It looks like your making a script that you're going to put into a bunch of different pages and use it to populate fields on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure this is what you are after, but I think it'll do the trick:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var name = filename.replace('.html','');

console.log(name);

$.ajax({
  url: '../content.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,

  success: function(data){
    if (data[name]) {
      $("#title").text(data[name].title);
      $("#image").attr('src', data[name].image);
      $("#link").text(data[name].linktitle)
                .attr('href', data[name].link);
    };
  }
});
```

Your Ajax query gets the content of `content.json`, parses it as JSON and passes the result to your `success` function.  Instead of doing something with every member of the function this just checks if the member you're interested in exists and if so, takes values from it and populates your page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was able to use `[]` to include a variable in  `$(data.name)`

The final code looks like this.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var name = filename.replace('.html','');

console.log(name);

$.ajax({
  url: '../content.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,

  success: function(data){
    $(data[name]).each(function(index, value) {
      $("#title").text(value.title);
      $("#image").attr('src', value.image);
      $("#link").attr('href', value.link);
      $("#link").text(value.linktitle);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That's doing more work, is a little more fragile, and harder to read than it needs to be, but that'll work.  What you're doing is essentially this: "Run this function for every member of whatever is stored in data[name]".  Since that's only ever one object for the data you have, you're good.